# How can I open .DAA file on a Mac Studio, Ventura 13.3.1

Tags: macos, iso-image

Mac Studio, macOS Ventura 13.3.1. I need to open a DAA file. I can’t because whatever programs I’ve tried are all X32 even though the DAA file was created on a X64 operating system. Windows7, years ago.

Comment: If you mean [DAAConverter](https://www.twilightedge.com/mac/daaconverter/) then you're going to need a Mac with Mojave or earlier to run it. Otherwise you need to be looking at a Windows solution.